# StackLayout with ngFor inside ScrollView

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to build an scrollable list by using a StackLayout with an ngFor (and a ScrollView, of course).

This is my code:

```
<StackLayout class="home-panel" verticalAlignment="top">
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <!--Suggest Append SuggetAppend -->
        <RadAutoCompleteTextView #autocmp [items]="items" suggestMode="Suggest" displayMode="Plain" width="80%">
            <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView suggestionViewHeight="300">
                <ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-item="item">
                    <StackLayout orientation="vertical" padding="10">
                        <Label [text]="item.text"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ng-template>
            </SuggestionView>
        </RadAutoCompleteTextView>

        <Button text="Add" (tap)="onAdd()" width="20%"></Button>
    </StackLayout>

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of this.shopList">
            <Label text="{{item}}" (tap)="itemSelected(item)" fontSize="36"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</StackLayout>
```

The problem arises with the ScrollView at the end of the main StackLayout, which apparently shows only the last element in the shoppingList. The functionality I want to have is a text box on top (with an 'add' button on the same line), and a scrollable list filling the rest of the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap your StackLayout with the *ngFor into another Layout container, so the ScrollView can calculate the height.

```
...
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of this.shopList"> 
                <Label text="{{item}}" fontSize="36"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
...
```